# How to implement arithmetic of infinite matrices?

Tags: matrix

Suppose we have infinite matrices defined by elements $a_{xy}=f(x,y)$. How can we implement arithmetic on them?

Comment: You can't really do that. see [dealing-with-infinite-matrices-in-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242416/dealing-with-infinite-matrices-in-mathematica)

Comment: @Nasser we cannot find a function $g(x,y)$ from $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$?

Comment: @Nasser I am speaking about matrices defined by a function of common element.